# How to rename a variable which respects the name scope?

Tags: tensorflow

Given `x, y` are tensors, I know I can do

```
with tf.name_scope("abc"):
    z = tf.add(x, y, name="z")
```

So that `z` is named `"abc/z"`.

I am wondering if there exists a function `f` which assign the name directly in the following case:

```
with tf.name_scope("abc"):
    z = x + y
    f(z, name="z")
```

The stupid `f` I am using now is `z = tf.add(0, z, name="z")`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to "rename" an op, there is no way to do that directly, because a `tf.Operation` (or `tf.Tensor`) is immutable once it has been created. The typical way to rename an op is therefore to use `tf.identity()`, which has almost no runtime cost:

```
with tf.name_scope("abc"):
    z = x + y
    z = tf.identity(z, name="z")
```

Note however that the recommended way to structure your name scope is to assign the name of the scope itself to the "output" from the scope (if there is a single output op):

```
with tf.name_scope("abc") as scope:
    # z will get the name "abc". x and y will have names in "abc/..." if they
    # are converted to tensors.
    z = tf.add(x, y, name=scope)
```

This is how the TensorFlow libraries are structured, and it tends to give the best visualization in TensorBoard.

Comment: Can you quote how you found out that [...] is the "recommended way"?

Comment: Not a quote exactly: I work on the TensorFlow team, so I helped to make up the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it works also without `tf.name_scope` only with `z = tf.identity(z, name="z_name")`. If you run additionally `z = tf.identity(z, name="z_name_new")` then you can access the same tensor using both names: `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("z_name:0")` or `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("z_name_new:0")`

Comment: Note: It's not the same Tensor. It's an extra Operation added to z, which does nothing. But it's two different Tensors with equal value.