# How to assign new name or rename an existing tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am experimenting Tensorflow C++ API. There is a need for me to name a tensor so that I can feed during reference in C++. Take a look at this example

```
self.initial_state = cell.zero_state(args.batch_size, tf.float32)
    print self.initial_state.name
```

self.initial_state is an tensor created by cell.zero_state method. My question is: How to rename / reassign a name to an existing tensor? I don't want to use the generated name for better recall.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try like:

```
some_tensor = tf.get_variable("my_old_tensor", [1, 2, 3])
new_tensor =  tf.identity(some_tensor, name="my_new_tensor")
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [How to rename a variable which respects the name scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399588/how-to-rename-a-variable-which-respects-the-name-scope) Answer section says: If you want to "rename" an op, there is no way to do that directly, because a tf.Operation (or tf.Tensor) is immutable once it has been created. The typical way to rename an op is therefore to use tf.identity().