# Assign name to an RNN next state in a TensorFlow graph

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a TensorFlow RNN model in which I make the following call

```
outputs, next_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_layers, embedded_input, initial_state=state)
```

I'd like to give a name to the `next_state` variable so that I can retrieve it later with `get_tensor_by_name`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it should already have a name (you should verify, if you haven't already).

If it doesn't, here is how to effectively assign a new name to a tensor:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34399966/447599

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to rename an operation is to use `tf.identity(),` which has almost no runtime cost:

```
outputs, next_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_layers, embedded_input, initial_state=state)
next_state = tf.identity(next_state, name='next_state_node')
```

later you can get the `next_state` by:

```
lstm_state = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('next_state_node:0')
```